Availability of Metal in pre-Mojave systems
Is it correct to consider:

that Metal is available on any Mac running Mojave or greater?
that Metal is unavailable on earlier systems if MTLCopyAllDevices() returns an empty array?

In other words, is this test correct in any case?
if (@available(macOS 10.14, *)) { 
    MetalCompatible = true;
} else {
    MetalCompatible = MTLCopyAllDevices().count > 0;
}

Incidentally, is there a better approach to test the availability of Metal on old macOS systems?


Metal has been available since OS X El Capitan (10.11)
@available(macOS 10.11, *) public func MTLCopyAllDevices() -> [any MTLDevice]

Detecting GPU Features and Metal Software Versions



I should have said that our app targets 10.11 but, you're right, my question would have been clearer if I have written else if (@available(macOS 10.11, *)). It's especially about 10.11 to 10.13 and the necessity to switch to openGL when the GPU doesn't support Metal, not about which version of Metal. The Apple doc is unclear about that, so I can just presume that if there is no MTLDevice, it means that Metal is unavailable (?) - which would also mean that there is no other possible failure (?). I'm just looking for a confirmation of that assumption.
